# Getting 401 error on api request using RestClient::Request authorization header in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, api, http

The api documentation calls for a returned token after authorizing using a username, password. I added the returned token, but I keep receiving a 401 response.

Here is the curl request in the api documentation:

```
curl \
  -H "Authorization: Token token=\"be08f1f4-c315-4d59-9c7c-d7a8b45a7db5\""
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://something.fake/api/lists
```

And here is my code using Rest::Client:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
    method: post,
    url:  https://something.fake/api/lists,
    :content_type => :json,
    :accept => :json,
    headers: {"Authorization" => "Token token=${token}"}
   )
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: A `401 Unauthorized Error` indicates that the requested resource is restricted and requires authentication, but the client failed to provide any such authentication. In your case, it means that your token has expired, hence you can't access the resources which need a valid token.

Answer (score 0):

The curl request has the token in quotes. So it won't be

```
token=be08f1f4-c315-4d59-9c7c-d7a8b45a7db5
```

it'll be

```
token="be08f1f4-c315-4d59-9c7c-d7a8b45a7db5"
```

so your code needs to be:

```
headers: {"Authorization" => "Token token=\"${token}\""}
```